# How to get user location in Facebook API v2.0?

Tags: facebook

I can get the basic information about user with following:

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log(location);
});
```

However I want to get the location of the user. How can I do that? I have tried to use /user method,

```
FB.api('/user', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

But I get following error

> (#803) Cannot query users by their username (user)

I will appreciate any help regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `/user` endpoint. To be able to query for `location`, you need to request the `user_location` permission, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0#reference-extended-profile

A sample request would be

```
FB.api('/me?fields=id,location', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```